# Are there technical dangers in mixing fstream and stdio?

Tags: c++, io

It is very clear that it's not a good practice to mix `iostream`/`fstream` with `stdio` and C-style i/o handling.

Printing one line with `printf(...)` and another one with `std:cout << ...`, or reading a file with `FILE*` and later writing with `ofstream` is ugly, can create confusion and is just asking for trouble.

However, is the only reason such practice is frowned upon basically just a stylistic / readability argument, or does it have deeper technical reasons?

I'm asking this because I need [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) in a small part of my code, doing some low-level register handling. `mmap` works with c-style file descriptors. However, in the rest of the code, I would like to go with the C++ stream route for handling files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical danger is decreased performance, as the two methods of output cannot be buffered independently. There's `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(bool)` to indicate such synchronization isn't needed (for instance because `<cstdio>` isn't used), but the default is slow and correct.